# MySQL select one row appearing multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a chat row and I want to fetch one row out of multiple (last row preferable).

The database looks like this...

[image: This is the image of the messages in that database row]

I need to fetch the last conversation (DISTINCT) between a user and others and display in a record set

One result per user we have had conversation with.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
select sender_id,receiver_id,message, count(*) 
  from chat 
  where (`sender_id` = '5' OR `receiver_id` = '5') 
  group by receiver_id, sender_id 
  HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Thanks.

Comment: select sender_id,receiver_id,message, count(*) from chat where 
(`sender_id` = '5' OR `receiver_id` = '5') 
and 
(message_date_time=(select max(message_date_time) from chat where sender_id=5))
group by receiver_id, sender_id;

Comment: It is not clear from your question what exact results you are looking for and what is wrong with what your have at the moment. Creating an http://sqlfiddle.com/ for it would really help you get an answer also.

Comment: So if user 5 had chats with users 1 and 2, no matter how often, we will see sender/receiver records in the table for 5/1, 1/5, 5/2, and 2/5. You want to select two messages/rows ony, the last one for 5/1 <-> 1/5, and the last one for 5/2 <-> 2/5. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

For user 5 you want the last row per other user. The other user is:

```
case when sender_id = 5 then receiver_id else sender_id end
```

The complete query:

```
select *
from chat
where (sender_id = 5 or receiver_id = 5)
and (case when sender_id = 5 then receiver_id else sender_id end, message_date_time) in
(
  select
    case when sender_id = 5 then receiver_id else sender_id end as other_user,
    max(message_date_time)
  from chat
  where sender_id = 5 or receiver_id = 5
  group by case when sender_id = 5 then receiver_id else sender_id end
);
```

As of MySQL 8.0 you can use `ROW_NUMBER` instead to rank your records per other user by datetime.

```
select *
from
(
  select
    chat.*,
    row_number() over (
      partition by case when sender_id = 5 then receiver_id else sender_id end
      order by message_date_time desc, id desc) as rn
  from chat
  where sender_id = 5 or receiver_id = 5
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```